# Index rebuild fail

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I have a 900 GB big table and 46GB index. Now my index is unusable state due to direct data load. While I am going to rebuild index for validation it is taking huge time and going to fail then. This is making big business problem. I am also not executing big business query due to this.

How can I make the index valid again?

One thing I have seen exec ctx_dll.sync_index( 'MY_INDEX' ). Is it supportable in my below database?

Below is my DB version

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

Comment: SO is not the right forum for DBA type questions.  Try https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @OldProgrammer This is not necessarily a DBA question.  At many organizations a problem like this would not be solved by a DBA.  Oracle developers frequently need to rebuild indexes.  This wouldn't be a horrible question for that other site, but it fits here as well.  (Although it could use some more details, like exactly how it fails.)

Comment: `ctx_dll.sync_index` is for Oracle Text indexes. Unless your​index is a CONTEXT index that is not going to help you. Is your table partitioned by any chance?

Comment: You need to rebuild the index.  If you are having trouble and it is production, I would first engage oracle support before this web site.  But, since you are here, things to consider (1) enable parallelism for the index rebuild if not already reset, you can reset it later, (2) is either your table or index partitioned, if so, you can rebuild partition by partition, (3) get more info on this comment, "it is going to fail then", like how is it failing?

Comment: Hi, i guess you should go for table partition.  You can create partition in such way that new data load goes in to new partition. So that  old data which are in partition will not be impacted and old Local index will be useful .

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do two things here

1) drop the index and create it again because rebuilding an require extra 46 GB of space in same tablespace if you omit tablespace name while rebuilding index.

2)rebuild index in some another tablespace where you have sufficient space.